# Fixed points of group actions in convex symmetric sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $X$  be a real vector space and $G$  be a group. Suppose that $G$  acts linearly on $X$, in the sense that for any $\alpha,\beta\in\left[0,1\right]$ , $g\in G$  and $x,y\in X$, we have
$$g(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha gx+\beta gy.$$
Say that a set $A\subseteq X$  is symmetric with respect to $G$  if, for all $g\in G$ , $gA=\left\{ gx:\: x\in A\right\} =A$.

**Question**: Give some conditions such that if $A$  is convex and symmetric, there exists $a\in A$  that is a fixed point with respect to $G$ , that is, for all $g\in G$ , $ga=a$ .

**Observation**: If $G$ is a finite group, the result has to be true. Simply take any $x\in A$ and define
$$a=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}gx.$$
So I'm interested in conditions that generalize this to infinite groups. Some counter-examples would also be cool.

Comment: Translations act linearly ("affinely" might be a better term) but don't have fixed points. If my intuition is right, they are basically the problem: G should be a subgroup of AGL(X), and the point stabilizers are isomorphic to GL(X).

Comment: The natural generalisation of your finite case is to amenable groups, which are essentially groups on which one can define a translation-invariant probability measure. There's a theorem that says something like "any affine action of an amenable group on a compact convex set has a fixed point".

Comment: Your new definition now ensures that G fixes 0, so that if my intuition is right, it implies G ≤ GL(X). If that is not the case, then ignore my intuition. If that is the case, then you are asking about a different part of the problem than I thought, so you can safely ignore me too. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I changed the definition of "linearly" to really mean linearly. So now this should rule out translations, since it implies $g0=0$.

Comment: Right, so say $G\leq GL(X)$. Does that mean the result is true?

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I had stumbled upon the definition of amenable group before, but I couldn't quite understand it and still can't. Maybe I just don't have enough background for it. Do you know any textbook treatment of it?

Comment: @Henrique: I learnt this material from classes so I don't have any recommendations for you, sorry. The definitions can certainly seem a bit dense at first... are you familiar with the Haar measure on locally compact groups? If not then find a good text on Topological groups and read up. The Haar measure on a compact group provides the most natural example of an infinite amenable group.

Comment: @Anthony: No, I'm not. I'll follow your advice and read up. Thanks!